# Fix Howl.js problem with hanlde multiple audio players after i create laravel php foreach loop for my audio files then i use this js code?

Tags: javascript, laravel, dom

this is the js code using Howl.js i wrote i hope someone can help me the problem is when i puase for first time then play again it reset the audio i want to keep track to the current audio that i playing then if i pause it i want if i play it again it play in the time i paused it in it so please if you can help or suggest solution give me it if that happen i will work to another approach to change current time by control progess but now i just focus on pause and play
here is the code

```
class AudioPlayer {
    constructor(srcAudio, srcAudioId) {
      this.srcAudio = srcAudio;
      this.srcAudioId = srcAudioId;
      this.isPlaying = false;
      this.seekPosition = 0;
  
      this.player = new Howl({
        src: srcAudio,
        html5: true,
        onplay: () => {
          this.isPlaying = true;
          console.log('onplay ' + this.srcAudioId);
        },
        onended: () => {
          this.isPlaying = false;
          console.log('onended ' + this.srcAudioId);
        },
        onpause: () => {
          this.isPlaying = false;
          this.seekPosition = this.player.seek();
          console.log('onpause ' + this.srcAudioId);
        },
        onseek: (event) => {
          console.log('onseek ' + this.srcAudioId);
          console.log(event);
        },
      });
    }
  
    play() {
      console.log('play ' + this.srcAudioId);
      this.player.seek(this.seekPosition);
      this.player.play();
      this.isPlaying = true;
    }
  
    pause() {
      console.log('pause ' + this.srcAudioId);
      this.seekPosition = this.player.seek();
      this.player.pause();
      this.isPlaying = false;
    }
  
    togglePlay() {
      if (this.player.playing([this.srcAudioId])) {
        this.pause();
      } else {
        this.play();
      }
    }
  }
  
  const audioModuleControll = (() => {
    let audioPlayers = {};
  
    function togglePlayAudio(element) {
      const srcAudio = element.getAttribute('data-audio');
      const srcAudioId = element.getAttribute('data-id');
  
      if (audioPlayers[srcAudioId]) {
        const player = audioPlayers[srcAudioId];
        player.togglePlay();
      } else {
        console.log('playing for the first time', srcAudioId);
        const player = new AudioPlayer(srcAudio, srcAudioId);
        player.play();
        audioPlayers[srcAudioId] = player;
      }
    }
  
    function addEventListenersFun() {
      const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.voice-assistant-item .playstory');
      playButtons.forEach(function(playButton) {
        playButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          togglePlayAudio(this);
        });
      });
    }
  
    return {
      addEventListenersFun: addEventListenersFun
    };
  })();
  
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    audioModuleControll.addEventListenersFun();
  });
```

Comment: solution i built a custom audio using new Audio object.